# How to rename currency name?

Tags: magento2, currency, luma-theme, currency-symbol

how can I change `"AED - United Arab Emirates Dirham" to "AED - UAE Dirham"` in Luma currency switcher?

I created **en_US.csv** file in my custom `theme > i18n` folder and added **"united Arab Emirates"** in the 1st column and **"UAE"** in the 2nd column. But still not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Override currency.phtml file in your theme

app/design/frontend/{vendore}/{theme}/Magento_Directory/templates/currency.phtml

> Change line number 35

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_code) ?> - <?= $block->escapeHtml($_name) ?>
```

> to

```
<?= __($block->escapeHtml($_code)) ?> - <?= __($block->escapeHtml($_name)) ?>
```

> Create app/design/frontend/{vendore}/{theme}/i18n/en_US.csv file and write below code

```
"United Arab Emirates Dirham","UAE Dirham"
```

> Change line number 28

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($currentCurrencyCode) ?> - <?= @$block->escapeHtml($currencies[$currentCurrencyCode]) ?>
```

> to

```
<?= __($block->escapeHtml($currentCurrencyCode)) ?> - <?= __(@$block->escapeHtml($currencies[$currentCurrencyCode])) ?>
```

I hope it's useful for you.

Comment: It worked. but only for currency drop down. after select "UAE - Dirham" from dropdown, "AED - United Arab Emirates Dirham" remains on top. how to apply for both places?

Comment: Please check I update the ans.

Comment: Yes now it's working. thank you so much :)

Comment: If my ans is useful than please give right. So another person also helpful.