# Change the name of the currency in currency selector in LUMA theme

Tags: magento2, multicurrency

I am triying to do the solution in the link below

[How to rename currency name?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275425/how-to-rename-currency-name)

I am using Magento 2.4 but i cant find the files, my directory is empty

> app/design/frontend/{vendore}/{theme}/Magento_Directory/templates/currency.phtml

**I changed the USD symbol to REF but the currency selector did not.**

[image]

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/currency-configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To change the currency symbol on the product page and other store front pages there is no need to modify template files. There is a setting

Store → Currency → Currency Symbols

[image]

2. The store switcher is a different story

Here I think you will have to modify the currency switcher like this in your local theme (note I used SEK you will have to replace this to your currency)

app/design/frontend/Custom/default/Magento_Directory/templates/currency.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->getCurrencyCount() > 1) : ?>
    <?php $currencies = $block->getCurrencies(); ?>
    <?php $currentCurrencyCode = $block->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>
    <?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : '' ?>
    <div class="switcher currency switcher-currency" id="switcher-currency<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>">
        <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Currency')) ?></span></strong>
        <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
            <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
                 id="switcher-currency-trigger<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>"
                 data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
                 data-toggle="dropdown"
                 data-trigger-keypress-button="true">
                <strong class="language-<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentCurrencyCode()) ?>">
                    <span><?= $currentCurrencyCode == 'SEK' ? 'REF' : $block->escapeHtml($currentCurrencyCode) ?> - <?= $currencies[$currentCurrencyCode] ? $block->escapeHtml($currencies[$currentCurrencyCode]) : '' ?></span>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
                <?php foreach ($currencies as $_code => $_name) : ?>
                    <?php if ($_code != $currentCurrencyCode) : ?>
                        <li class="currency-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code) ?> switcher-option">
                            <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSwitchCurrencyPostData($_code) ?>'><?= $_code == 'SEK' ? 'REF' : $block->escapeHtml($_code) ?> - <?= $block->escapeHtml($_name) ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]